# RemovalListener for auto-eviction events only

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm using a guava LoadingCache with eviction policy set expireAfterWrite(). I also invalidate entries on access using:

```
v = cache.getIfPresent( k );
if( v != null ) {
  cache.invalidate( k );
}
```

Is there a way to add a RemovalListener that gets fired only when entries get auto-evicted  after the write timeout is hit? From documentation, it appears that the RemovalListener is called any time an entry is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a `RemovalListener` will be called any time any entry is removed -- but the `RemovalListener` will receive a `RemovalNotification` object, which includes the *cause*, which you can use to determine how an entry got removed.

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .removalListener(new RemovalListener<Foo, Bar>() {
    public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<Foo, Bar> notification) {
      if (notification.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
        // we only care about these removals
      }
    }
  })
  .build();
```

Comment: Perfect! I do love guava caches!

Comment: Actually you can just call `wasEvicted()` on the notification directly!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution mainly if you're looking for performance. 
Should be MUTCH better if you have a way to receive only evicted entries.
IMHO